# Pig:FLATTEN keyword

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I am a little confused with the use of `FLATTEN` keyword in PIG.

Consider the below dataset:

```
tuple_record: {details: (firstname: chararray,lastname: chararray,age: int,sex: chararray)}
```

Without using the `FLATTEN` I can access a field (suppose firstname) like this:

```
display_firstname = FOREACH tuple_record GENERATE details.firstname;
```

Now, using the `FLATTEN` keyword:

```
flatten_record = FOREACH tuple_record GENERATE FLATTEN(details);
```

`DESCRIBE` gives me this:

```
flatten_record: {details::firstname: chararray,details::lastname: chararray,details::age: int,details::sex: chararray}
```

And hence I can access the fields present directly without `dereferencing` like this:

```
display_record = FOREACH flatten_record GENERATE firstname;
```

My questions related to this `FLATTEN` keyword is:

1) Which way among the two (i.e. with or without using `FLATTEN`) is the optimized way of achieving the same output?

2) Any special scenarios where without using the `FLATTEN` keywords, the desired output cant be achieved?

Totally confused; please clarify its use and in which all scenarios I shall use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Sometimes you have data in a bag or a tuple and you want to remove that level of nesting.
2. when you want to switch around your data on the fly and group by a particular field, you need a way to pull those entries out of the bag.

As per Pig documentation:

> The FLATTEN operator looks like a UDF syntactically, but it is
>   actually an operator that changes the structure of tuples and bags in
>   a way that a UDF cannot. Flatten un-nests tuples as well as bags. The
>   idea is the same, but the operation and result is different for each
>   type of structure.

For more details check [this link](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#flatten) they have explained the usage of FLATTEN clearly with examples